# Deploying Google Script (as private) to G Suite Market Place vía Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, chrome-web-store

I've tried to deploy a script we made as an addon for google sheets and we decided to make it private so only the members of the organization can find it and use it.

I've used this video in order to do so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jcc3xm7aRU&list=WL&index=2&t=0s

The problem is, after finishing all the steps, it still is not up in the G Suite Market Place:

- The option to add it is grayed out
  [image]
- Chrome web store shows a message saying I've published 0 out of 20 allowed elements
  [image]
- However, in the alternative control panel, it shows as published
  [image]
- And when I try to find it vía Google Sheets -> download addons, and look under my organization option, it says nothing has been published
  [image]

I've read somewhere that a developer account needs to pay one time fee of $5? However, I haven't seen this option anywhere.

I thought that when you publish as 'private' it wouldn't have such issues. Any insight on where else to check?

**Update:**

- Made the $5 payment.. crossing fingers..

[image]

- Used the link as another user of the organization. Still the same message "changes will apply in a few minutes" with the Add to Chrome grayed out.. 
  The thing is, it is not supossed to take that long for a private addon.. but can't be 100% sure.

[image]

- Tried to be redirected to the addon in G Suite Marketplace using the link in the Chrome Developer Control Panel, however it redirected to the main page of the G Suite Marketplace. Will try to find the Addon inside the Marketplace using it's ID

[image]

**UPDATE**

- I've updated the version (currently version 3)
  [image]
- Went to Google Cloud Platform -> API & Services -> G Suite Marketplace SDK -> Configuration and update the version
  [image]
- Integrated with Google 
  [image]
- It loaded a new sheets but without the addon.. However this error showed in Cloud.. It appears it is now integrated with all the sheets that the organizations will create at any time, but something is wrong in the code.
  [image]
- Managed to make it available to the organization but still it dosn't load in any sheet
  [image]

**Code:**

```
function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e){
  Logger.log('entré al menú')
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Plataforma')
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Liquidaciones')
              .addItem('Nueva LiQ', 'NuevaVenta')
              .addSeparator()
             .addItem('Actualizar LiQ', 'ActualizarFichaLiq'))
  .addItem('Guardar LiQ', 'ValidacionCostos')
  .addSeparator()
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Voucher')
              .addItem('Generar Voucher', ''))
      .addToUi();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Add-ons are currently being [migrated](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration) from the Chrome WebStore to the G Suite Marketplace, this is why some features currently do not work as expected

However, it is possible to install private (domain-wide published) Add-ons in the following manner:

1. Go to `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard` and click in `Your listings` on the Add-on you want to install
2. Clicking on the link will open you Add-on in GSuite Marketplace
3. From here you can install your Add-on - either individually or domain-wide

[image]
4.After installing the Add-on, you should see it in the menu of Google Spreadsheets

[image]

5. Going on `Manage add-ons` will bring you to the list of your installed Add-ons

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi!
I'm failing on step 2. After clicking on the add-on on my listings, it takes me to g-suite market place but not exactly to the addon, but to their main page (will update question with screenshot).
I'll try to see if I can find it in any other way (with the element ID maybe)

Comment: This is strange. Are you sure that after the last edit of your code, you published as a new version and also update the G Suite Marketplace SDK with the new Add-on script version?

Comment: I was checking just that, and I think I almost found what was wrong.. however it seems the code is not correct and that is why it is not launching at the opening of any sheets. (Updated the question with the progress on this issue).

Comment: So you can find your add-on on Marketplace now? This means that this problem is solved. As for the code - that is already a different, not related issue. At the first glance, I would recommend you to use add-on menus: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/menus Keep in mind that the error can also originate from on of the functions linked to the different items or from lacking scopes. To debug, I recommend you to test your code as add-on: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons

Comment: Sadly, the status is the same, it still doesn't show up in the G Suite Marketplace, although it has been update in the SDK and everything else in Google Cloud.. No idea really what to do next. It might be the migration you mentioned in your answer but not sure. I'll keep an eye on it if anything changes in the next days

Comment: It just came to my knowledge that the g suite account we are using are the very old free edition (that with 50+ accounts available)... could this be the reason for all this chaos? :) (I can't ask google tech support because we don't have that on this kind of account omg lol)

Comment: I wouldn"t know about this. I just did not  quite understand you - when you click on the Add-on listing in Chrome WebStore - are you being redirected to it"s GSuite Marketplace listing where you have the option to install it?

Comment: Noup, same as before, I get redirected to the main page of G Suite Marketplace